# Ajax return and append HTML data into table row

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem with ajax return html data.
Idea is I have dynamic table that user can add or delete table row, in each of table row there is button that will show modals and user can choose Item, but after user add rows and choose item, item goes to first rows not to new row.

Please your help.

this is my HTML:

```
    <tr id='addr0' class="itemsGroup">
                    <td>
                    1
                    </td>
                    <td width="240px">
                      <div class="input-group" >
               <input type="text" name="barang_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo @$rowID->barang_id != '' ? $rowID->barang_id : $this->session->flashdata('barang_id') ;?>">
               <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                <a href="#myModalItems" class="trash" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a></span>
                      </div>
              </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="barang_name[]" class="form-control" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="barang_satuan[]" class="form-control" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="barang_unit_price[]" class="form-control" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="barang_qty[]" class="form-control" >
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

My Modal :

```
<div class="modal-header">      
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Items</h4>
   </div> 
    <div class="modal-body"><div class="panel panel-default" >
                   <div class="panel-heading">
                    <table id="mytablex" class="display" > 
                        <thead>
                         <tr >
                          <th width="55px"  style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;</th>
                          <th width="55px"  style="text-align:center;">No.</th>
                          <th width="240px" style="text-align:center;">Item No.</th>
                          <th width="240px" style="text-align:center;">Item Name</th>
                         </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php 
                           $counter = 1;
                          if ($resultBarang) {
                           foreach ($resultBarang as $row) {

                            if ($counter%2 ==0) { $class = 'list01';}else {$class = 'list02';}    
                             ?>
                          <tr class="<?php echo $class;?>">
                           <td width="55px" align="center"><input type="radio" onclick="getItemsID(this.value);" name="supid" id="supid" value="<?php echo $row->barang_id;?>"></td>
                           <td width="55px" align="center"><?=$counter?>.</td>
                           <td width="240px" ><?=$row->barang_no;?></td>
                           <td width="240px" ><?=$row->barang_name;?></td>
                           </tr>
                          <?php $counter++;}} ?>
                        </tbody>

                        </table>
                         </div>
                        </div>
     </div>   
     <div class="modal-footer">
             <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button> 
          </div> 

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

after select checkbox i'm using this script :

```
 function getItemsID(supid){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/po_trans_po/getItemsId',
        data:'id='+supid,
                  success: function(data){
                      $(".itemsGroup").html(data);
            $('#myModalItems').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    }
```

and then this is my PHP file :

```
  function getItemsId()
 {
   $id = $this->input->post('id');   
   $resultBarang = $this->db->query("select * from `st_po_barang`  a,st_po_harga_barang c
                   where c.barang_id = a.barang_id
                   and now() between c.harga_start_date and c.harga_end_date
                   and a.barang_id = $id
                   ");

   $resultBarang =  $resultBarang->row();
    echo '              <td>               ';
    echo '              1                  ';
    echo '              </td>              ';
    echo '              <td width="240px"> ';
    echo '                <div class="input-group" >';
  echo ' <input type="text" name="barang_id" class="form-control" value="'.$resultBarang->barang_no.'"> ';
    echo '           <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">                                                                                                           ';
    echo '            <a href="#myModalItems" class="trash" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a></span>                            ';
    echo '                </div>                                                                                                                                                        ';
    echo '          </td>                                                                                                                                                         ';
    echo '              <td>                                                                                                                                                            ';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="barang_name[]" value="'.$resultBarang->barang_name.'" class="form-control" >                                                                                                  ';
    echo '              </td>                                                                                                                                                           ';
    echo '              <td>                                                                                                                                                            ';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="barang_satuan[]" value="'.$resultBarang->barang_satuan.'"class="form-control" >                                                                                                ';
    echo '              </td>                                                                                                                                                           ';
    echo '              <td>                                                                                                                                                            ';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="barang_unit_price[]" value="'.$resultBarang->harga_beli.'"class="form-control" >                                                                                            ';
    echo '              </td>                                                                                                                                                           ';
    echo '              <td>                                                                                                                                                            ';
    echo '              <input type="text" name="barang_qty[]" class="form-control" >                                                                                                   ';
    echo '              </td>                                                                                                                                                            ';

   return 1;
   //redirect('admin/po_trans_po');
 }
```

If i'm adding row table data , this return data keep in first row in table.
How to return data in selected row?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` to add data in table has class itemsGroup

```
function getItemsID(supid){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/po_trans_po/getItemsId',
            data:'id='+supid,
                      success: function(data){
                          $(".itemsGroup").append(data);
                $('#myModalItems').modal('hide');
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: I've already update with append but no luck, table row will add <td> with items inside , thanks

Comment: use .itemsGroup in <table class="itemsGroup"> and return <tr> in .ajax response

Comment: same result . because if 1 row is working fine, but if user add row then selected items in modals keep showing in first row not in new row.

Comment: i'm using bootstrap modal ,  <a href="#myModalItems" class="trash" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a> so i'm not adding javascript to show modals

Comment: use this might it will help you $(document).ready(function () {
           
            $('body').on('click', '.trash', function () {
               
                
                  $('#myModalItems').modal({show: true});
                 
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rowid when user click modals then i change javascript code into :

```
function getItemsID(supid){
        ptrid = $('#ptrid').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/po_trans_po/getItemsId',
        data:'id='+supid+'&ptrid='+ptrid,
                  success: function(data){
                      $('#'+ptrid).closest("tr").html(data);
                      $('#myModalItems').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    }
```

ptrid is rowid that i pass when click modals.
thanks